# How to slide tableCell to show hidden interaction in UIAutomation iOS 7

Tags: ios, automation, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

I am trying to figure out how to get a hidden button to appear on table cell. Similar to if you were looking at the SMS app on iPhone. The threads are in table cells and if you touch and drag across that cell, a button to delete that thread appears. The functionality in my application is similar.

Now I would like to automate the testing of being able to delete a thread with this method.

```
target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().scrollViews()[0].tableViews()[0].visibleCells()[0].dragInsideWithOptions({startOffset:{x:0.9, y:0.5}, endOffset:{x:0.0, y:0.5}, duration: 1.5});
```

The above currently seems to start the intended interaction, but then the UI snaps back as if the action did not happen.

Answer (score 0):

If you run this manually, does the cell stays on one side or does it always snaps back? The reason I ask is because I have a similar UI but I'm able to slide the cell all the way to one side and then tap on the buttons behind it. If you only drag the cell half way, then it will ignore the taps.

Comment: Apparently, I just never saw this response. Though as of recently I have had to make a lot of changes to my UI Automation suite. So when I do return to this specific test case I will try coding a drag that does the length of the cell and will report back.